# Outlook add-in activation rule for compose new appointment

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I'm developing an Outlook mail app using vs 2015. I want to show my add-in only when the existing calendar item is opened. When I have the `FormType` as `ReadOrEdit` in `Rule Collection` of manifest, the add-in shows for the appointment while creating itself. i.e. new appointment also has add-in. I don't want to show the add-in while creating a new appointment.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `FormType` to `Read`. Then it will be shown only when you open existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Changing FormType to Read doesn't help. Read works for meeting appointment created by other users. If the user is the Organizer of the appointment, add-in doesn't show.